# How to bind @Param for @Query annotations on repository methods in spring data mongodb?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am using the latest spring boot with spring-data-mongodb where I am trying to bind repository method parameters with @Param to the queries in a @Query annotation.  I have seen several examples for spring data using JPA, but not much for spring-data-mongodb.  This is what I have tried:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'bar': :param1 }")
FooModel getFooBySomeParam(@Param("param1") final String p1);
```

I am not currently at work, so I do not have the specific error, but the error was when it was parsing the query string.  It was looking for a value but found a colon.  I am assuming that I am specifying the named parameter incorrectly, thus parsing is failing when it encounters the leading colon before the parameter name, but I have not seen how to do this differently with mongodb repositories.

Comment: I think that it might be something like this: @Query("{ bar: :#{#param1} }")

Comment: It is ```@Query(value = "{ 'bar': ?0}")```

Comment: @Harshit, Please re-read the question.  I know how to do *positional arguments*, but I am trying to get bound named parameters to work.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Yes you are right, it works with ```@Query("{ bar: :#{#param1} }")``` and is called SpEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure this out for spring-data-mongodb, it is different than the spring-data-jpa version.  You cannot prefix the bound parameter name with only a colon.  It would be nice to know why the Spring developers did not maintain consistency here, but the source code reveals that bound param names can be referenced like `:#{#boundParamName}` or `?#{#boundParamName}` when you have a query method parameter like `@Param("boundParamName") final String someStringValue`.

Also note that, either `Collection` parameter variables, like `List` or `Set` do not get translated properly for repository query methods with `@Query` annotations, or I have been doing it incorrectly.  Instead, convert the collection to an array (in your business logic) and pass it to the query method as an array.  That is another aspect that tripped me up for a while.

Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: 2022 UPDATE:  I have been using collection parameters with these annotations, and it works without requiring the conversion to an array, at least with a collection of strings.